# Converted DVI to EPS is larger then the underlying graphic

Tags: pstricks, dvips

I use this code for generating a graphic:

```
\documentclass[dvips]{article}
\usepackage{pst-all}
\usepackage{pst-3dplot}
\usepackage{pst-eps}
\usepackage{pst-dbicons}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{TeXtoEPS}
\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont
\psset{xunit=1cm,yunit=1cm,runit=1cm}
\begin{pspicture}(11,11)
    \psframe[linewidth=2pt,framearc=.3,fillstyle=none](0.5,0.5)(10.5,10.5)

    \rput(4,10.5){\psframebox*{\Large Datenbanksystem}}

    \psframe[fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=lightgray](1.5,6)(9.5,9)

    \rput(5.5,7.4){\psframebox*[fillcolor=lightgray]{\Large Datenbankmanagementsystem}}

    \rput(5.5,3.25){\database{3.5cm}{2cm}[fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=gray]{Datenbanken}}

\end{pspicture}

\end{TeXtoEPS}

\end{document}
```

when I convert it with 
    dvips Grafik1.dvi -E -o Grafik1.eps

I expect a graphic with 1:1 ratio. But it added some white Border to the left hand side:

[image: Image with white Border]

Any idea what happened and what I could do to fix this?

Comment: What if you put a `\noindent` in front of your `\begin{pspicture}`?

Comment: Doesn't change anything

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what's wrong with `dvips -E`, but I got a much better result with

```
dvips Grafik1.dvi -o Grafik1.ps
ps2eps --ignoreBB Grafik1.ps
```

Comment: This workaround solves the Problem